# SQL update statement based unique value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, distinct

I am trying to do an SQL UPDATE query to set a value for b.[Disposition] WHERE the i.uid field is unique

The following select statement returns the correct rows.

```
Select distinct i.* 
FROM   [dbo].[Imported] i 
  inner join [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline] b 
     on b.[CLI] = i.[CLI] 
    and b.[Quantity] = i.[Quantity] 
    and b.[UnitCost] = i.[UnitCost] 
    and b.[TotalCost] = i.[TotalCost] 
    and b.[Description] = i.[Description]
```

However I am unsure how to incorporate that into an SQL UPDATE statement.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add sample data and expected result to make it clear

Comment: Does baseline table also contains UID column ?

Comment: what you like b.disposition equal to a. ?

Comment: Yes, the two tables both contain identical fields

Comment: b. disposition to = 'myspecifiedvalue'

Comment: `Join` predicates really looks odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE upb
SET b.Disposition  = "YOUR VALUE"
FROM  [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline] ubp
INNER JOIN (Select distinct i.* FROM [dbo].[Imported] i 
inner join [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline] b on 
b.[CLI]=i.[CLI] AND 
b.[Quantity]=i.[Quantity] AND 
b.[UnitCost]=i.[UnitCost] AND 
b.[TotalCost]=i.[TotalCost] AND 
b.[Description]=i.[Description] )tmp ON Tmp.UID = ubp.UID
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but you can do something like this

```
update b
set -- your fields here
FROM [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline] b
inner join [dbo].[Imported] i on 
b.[CLI]=i.[CLI] AND 
b.[Quantity]=i.[Quantity] AND 
b.[UnitCost]=i.[UnitCost] AND 
b.[TotalCost]=i.[TotalCost] AND 
b.[Description]=i.[Description]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code doesn't handle the uniqueness I require. the key in the select statement in my example is that I only select from i.* if my select statement uses just *, to many results are returned

Comment: @user3580480 - Hope now you understood why I asked for sample data and result in first place. You are making everyone to guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works..Mention the column name equal to

```
   update b
    set b.disposition =  i.xxxx from [dbo].[Imported] i 
    inner join [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline] b on 
    b.[CLI]=i.[CLI] AND 
    b.[Quantity]=i.[Quantity] AND 
    b.[UnitCost]=i.[UnitCost] AND 
    b.[TotalCost]=i.[TotalCost] AND 
    b.[Description]=i.[Description]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update [b].[Disposition] set x(Desired value)
from [dbo].[Imported] i inner join [DaisyCompare].[dbo].[Baseline] b on 
b.[CLI]=i.[CLI] AND 
b.[Quantity]=i.[Quantity] and
b.[UnitCost]=i.[UnitCost] and
b.[TotalCost]=i.[TotalCost] and
b.[Description]=i.[Description] where i.uid = y(Desired value)
```

Comment: You forgot to add the WHERE i.uid = '' constraint, per the OPs request.